# C++ cout pointer

Tags: c++

Hello
Can somebody explain why second **cout** in func(char *p) doesn't work:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

char *strhex(char *str);
char *func(char *p);

int  main()
{
     char *ptr;    

     char *p=strhex("d");
     cout<<"main:"<<p<<endl;

     cout<<func(p)<<endl;

     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;
}

char *func(char *p)
{ 
      cout<<"func1:"<<p<<endl;
      char buffer[500]="";
   char *zbuffer = buffer; 
      cout<<"func2:"<<p<<endl; ///doesn't work

      return zbuffer;
}

char *strhex(char *str)
{
     char buffer[500]="";
  char *pbuffer = buffer;
  int len = strlen( str );

     for( int i = 0; i < len ;i++ )
  {
  itoa(str[i],pbuffer,16);  
        pbuffer +=2;
     };

     *pbuffer = '\0'; 
     pbuffer=buffer;

     return pbuffer;
}
```

Edit:
i'm using DEV C++ 4.9.9.2 on Windows

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?"

Comment: Returning a pointer to a local variable is probably bad idea, but likely unrelated to your problem.

Comment: @Carl: Probably the exact cause, actually.  The stack space occupied by `buffer` in `strhex()` will be occupied by `buffer` in `func()`.

Comment: You're returning pointers to stack variables. These pointers aren't valid when you try to use them.

Comment: @Oli - good catch.  I only read the one function `func()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One big problem here is that `strhex` is returning a pointer to a local variable (`buffer[]`).  This variable goes out of scope at the end of the function, so the return value points at undefined memory contents that can be overwritten at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire code doesn't work. Both functions return pointers to local arrays, which don't point to anything valid after the function returns. That causes undefined behavior. Since the value of `p` is one of these invalid pointers, you can't depend on it to be anything at any particular time — that memory probably gets overwritten during `func()`. You need to either `new[]` and `delete[]` the appropriate memory or, preferably, use a proper C++ data structure like `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it is working but the second cout in main is not printing out a value because you are returning an empty buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to others answers:

You need not reset `pbuffer` to point to the start of the array and then return it's value:

```
pbuffer=buffer;
return pbuffer;
```

you can just say

```
return buffer;
```

the array name is also a pointer(pointer to the first element of the array.